C++ why does my message size change randomly after exiting a loop?
I'm using zmq to send messages and in my function for accepting a response for some reason when i exit the loop the 8th value always seems to spike up to a crazy high random number.
I tried putting couts to see where the value changes. When I check the size of part after its pushed into messages (and compare it to the vector inside the loop), it seems normal and all values are to be expected, but as soon as it exits the do while loop, and i iterate through the messages vector it changes only the 8th value but is correct for everything after the 8th value. Ive tried to make sure all unused messages were closed, but i'm not really sure how they would change anything. I also checked to see if the sent messages were correct and they were so im pretty stumped.
    int more;
    size_t more_size = sizeof(more);
    std::vector<zmq_msg_t> messages;
    int counter = 0;
    do {
      zmq_msg_t part;
      rc = zmq_msg_init(&part);
      rc = zmq_msg_init_size(&part, CHUNK_SIZE);
      /* Block until a message is available to be received from socket */
      rc = zmq_msg_recv(&part, clientSocket_, 0);
      assert(rc != -1);

      // Add the string to the vector
      messages.push_back(part);
      /* Determine if more message parts are to follow */
      rc = zmq_getsockopt(clientSocket_, ZMQ_RCVMORE, &more, &more_size);
      assert(rc == 0);
      zmq_msg_close(&part);
    } while (more);

    for (zmq_msg_t msg : messages) {
      std::cout << "message size: " << zmq_msg_size(&msg) << std::endl;
    }

Output below.
message size: 1024
message size: 1024
message size: 1024
message size: 1024
message size: 1024
message size: 1024
message size: 1024
message size: 139644284960912
message size: 1024
... (keeps going)


Message is not guaranteed to be useful after zmq_msg_close(). If you want to output sizes then store sizes.

To me, this looks a lot like a C-style interface with that zmq_msg_t not being copyable.

@ÖöTiib I'm not outputting sizes I was using sizes to see what was going wrong with the code. I have code further down that makes sure that the message size is 1024 or less and it kept returning an error so I started checking the sizes of the messages and found exactly where one of the values randomly changed.

@Justin anyway that zeromq seems to provide C++ wrapper  https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq so why you use naked zmq_msg_t and rest of C API of it in C++?

@ÖöTiib I didn't know that. I was reading the book on the library and was basing my code on that. I'll take a look thanks!

This is just a simple sketch for a wrapper class -- I haven't tried it, since I don't even have that library available. You should still be able to get the idea and possibly fix things that don't work as intended.
class MyZmsg
{
private:
   std::unique_ptr<zmq_msg_t> message;

public:
   MyZmsg()
   {
      auto msg=std::make_unique<zmq_msg_t>();
      if (zmq_msg_init(msg.get())!=0) throw std::bad_alloc();
      message=std::move(msg);
   }

   ~MyZmsg()
   {
      if (message) zmq_msg_close(message.get());
   }

   operator zmq_msg_t*() const noexcept
   {
      return message.get();
   }
};

This should me movable, but not copyable (because of the unique_ptr), so you can stick it into the vector. It does the init/close for you already, and the conversion operator should allow you to just use an instance of this instead of the &part.
Usage example:
std::vector<MyZmsg> messages;
...
MyZmsg part;
...
rc = zmq_msg_init_size(part, CHUNK_SIZE);
...
messages.push_back(std::move(part));

